# Is there a simple way to flatten a JSON object properties using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given an entity class with a compound key that is managed by hibernate is there a simple way to flatten the keys properties into the object itself?

Given:

```
{
    "key": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2
    },
    "prop": "value"
}
```

I would prefer this to be serialized as:

```
{
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2,
    "prop": "value"
}
```

I really don't want to have to implement `JsonSerializableWithType` as it's fine at the moment, it's just that key class I want the fields flattened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson uses reflection, and you can manipulate getters/setters. You can add `@JsonIgnore` to `getKey()`, and add two methods

```
@JsonProperty("field1")
private int getField1()

@JsonProperty("field2")
private int getField2()
```

You may want to implement `setField1()` and `setField2()` as well.

Comment: Ah of course, why didn't I think of that. No need for setters as the objects are read only, besides, changing a PK is a bad idea. :)